# how to host django project in ubuntu using wsgi_mod

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

I created sample django project in /var/www/firstproject, which I configured using [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-mod_wsgi-to-serve-applications-on-ubuntu-12-04)

```
firstproject.conf in etc/apache2/sites-available
```

But I got forbidden error.
How can I solve the error, and help to host my project?

Answer (score 1):

you are not given proper explanation about your error.

required packages:

- Apache2
- libapache2-mod-wsgi
- Django

Create Empty Project

- cd  /var/www
- sudo virtualenv foldername
- cd foldername
- sudo django-admin.py startproject  projectname
- cd projectname
- sudo nano projectname.wsgi

projectname.wsgi file

```
 import os 
 import sys 
 sys.path.append('/var/www/foldername/projectname') 
 os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'projectname.settings' 
 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application 
 application = get_wsgi_application()
```

- cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
- sudo nano projectname.conf

projectname.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.example.com   
    ServerAlias  www.example.com   
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foldername/projectname 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/foldername/projectname/projectname.wsgi 
    Alias /static /var/www/foldername/static/static_only 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
 </VirtualHost>
```

sudo nano  /etc/hosts

you need to add following line into hosts file

```
your_ip www.example.com
```

Goto your project location and run python manage.py collectstatic
now your local files copies are inside the static_only folder

may be you are  getting "Attempt to write a readonly database " error ,this permission issue  so you need to run following command .

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/foldername
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/foldername/projectname/db.sqlite3
```

now type www.example.com on your browser

Comment: I missed to include the Document root line and also got the error 'attempt to write a read-only database'. It helps to solve my issue.Thanks for your valuable answer.